# Python Sqlite3 advanced grouping

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I hope this question has not been asked before. I have a csv file containing below columns and info and I can upload this to sqlite3 database with the exact same column names

```
Company Type Qty Price
ABC      r    5   $$$
ABC      h    9   $$$
ABC      s    10  $$$
DER      a    3   $$$
DER      z    6   $$$
GGG      q    12  $$$
GGG      w    20  $$$
```

but, how do I get the below result on a csv file? Basically, grouping by the company name and still showing Type, Qty and Price, and at the end of lines showing the total qty for each company.

```
Company Type Qty Price Total Qty
ABC     r    5   $$$      
        h    9   $$$
        s    10  $$$      24
DER     a    3   $$$
        z    6   $$$      9
GGG     q    12  $$$
        w    20  $$$      32
```

I have been trying with GROUP BY, but no luck.
Any help is much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can do that with a SQL expression including `UNION`.But why don't you separate this in two expressions: The first is selecting and ordering the data and the second one is doing the group by and the sum. If you post the code to create and fill the db I can help you further.

Comment: I will do it and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using a combination of SQL and [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

For example, something like:

```
results = cxn.execute("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY Company")
for company, orders_iter in itertools.groupby(results, key=lambda r: r[0]):
    orders = list(orders_iter)
    total_qty = sum(order[2] for order in orders)
    ... print out orders ...
```

Someone with more SQL-foo than I have might be able to come up with a query which would produce exactly the results that you want… But that's probably unnecessary, especially given that, with some minor modifications (calculating the total while iterating over the orders), the Python code would only need `O(n)` time and `O(1)` memory.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working. I will play around with this.

Comment: Instead of creating a list of orders, you can duplicate the iterator with `itertools.tee`.

Comment: @ms4py what advantage will that have? In the example I have, it will still have to store a copy of the list.

Comment: @Python_Rocks Cool, no problem. Once you've confirmed it has answered your question, hit the checkbox below the voting-on-the-answer box to accept it (and if you think it's especially good, maybe give it an upvote too).